# Пунктуация в конце предложений

Tags: пунктуация

Возле некоторых вольеров можно увидеть предупреждающие вывески: «Осторожно, пони кусаются!» или «Олень тянет за одежду!». Чем-то это напоминает частный сектор в Геленджике с надписями на воротах «Осторожно, злая собака!».

Answer (score 2):

Что именно вам не нравится в конце предложения? Наличие восклицательного знака? В объявлениях такого рода содержится предупреждение, поэтому ставятся соответствующие знаки препинания. Наличие подобных табличек снимает ответственность за проблемы, которые могут возникнуть из-за несоблюдения  каких-либо правил, невнимательности или халатности  с тех, кто их пишет.

Answer (score 1):

А вопрос в чем?
Не нравится восклицательный знак?
Он здесь вполне на месте. 
Теоретически можно и без него, но когда идет прямое обращение к читающему, да еще сопровождаемое "осторожно!", как-то сомнение в его уместности совсем не возникает.

> меня смущает количество знаков друг за другом (!".)Нужна ли точка за скобками?

На табличке кавычки и точка не нужна. Вы же не хотите сказать, что кто-то пишет эти эти знаки на самих табличках?!

Что касается самого Вашего текста и аналогичных предложений, то точку рекомендую  оставить. Хотя тут случай действительно дискуссионный. Часто можно встретить рекомендацию не ставить точку после закрывающей кавычки, если перед кавычкой идет другой знак (вопросительный, восклицательный, многоточие). Мы тут это обсуждали.  Кажется, не один раз. Сошлись на том, что эта рекомендация, даже если принять её к исполнению, относится только к прямой речи. 
Так что Ваш текст написан с точки зрения пунктуации корректно, все знаки на месте.

Comment: меня смущает количество знаков друг за другом (!".)Нужна ли точка за скобками?

Comment: Так так бы и сказали.
См. мой ответ.